# Is there any way I can write data to json from Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I have a test json hosted at https://dkapps54.github.io/jsonTestApp/message.json
I want to make an app, with two editTexts. I want that the text in one should replace the "title" field in the json and the other to replace the "message". Is this possible?

If yes, which command is used to do it? (I'm using Volley)

Here's my code for receiving the message (i.e. requesting data from Json):

```
package com.example.jsonmessagereceive;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView title;
    TextView message;
    Button refresh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        title = findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
        message = findViewById(R.id.textView_message);
        refresh = findViewById(R.id.button_refresh);

        refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String[] titleText = {""};
                final String[] messageText = {""};
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://dkapps54.github.io/jsonTestApp/message.json",
                        null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    titleText[0] = response.getString("title");
                                    messageText[0] = response.getString("message");
                                    title.setText(titleText[0]);
                                    message.setText(messageText[0]);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in Response!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error by ErrorListener!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the JSON after you have amended it with user input?

Comment: @codebod Well, this is just an app I'm building for fun while learning. Basically, there will be two apps, one which can send specific messages, and another which can only view this message.

Comment: Start by creating a simple request such as at https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#simple and verify in Logcat that the response is valid. Then show what you've done and we'll take it from there.

Comment: @codebod I already know how to request data from Json. However, I built the app for showing the message first, as you said. Please see edited question,

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not clear on what flow you're trying to achieve. Is the next step to alter your `JSONObject` with the contents of 2 `EditText` views? Should a user press a button to update the `JSONObject` or do you want entering text to automatically result in that object being amended?

Comment: @codebod No no no, you got me wrong here. I am building 2 apps. The code of one is in the question. Now, I want to build the other, which will have 2 editTexts and a button. The button is clicked and whatever is in the first EditText should be the "title" value in json and the text in 2nd EditText should be the message value. TD;DR Please tell me the function or whatever that is used to change text in a json (if possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's part of the code you could use:

```
private EditText editTextTitle;
private EditText editTextMessage;

JSONObject buildJsonObject() {
    String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    if (validateInput(title, message)) {
         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("title", title);
            obj.put("message", message);
            return obj;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean validateInput(String title, String message) {
    // check that the Strings meet whatever validation criteria you have (e.g. length, character set) and return true if all good.
    // present a message (e.g. Toast) if validation failed and return false.
}
```

In your `onCreate` method you will need to initialise your 2x `EditText` and register an `OnClickListener` on a button, whose `onClick` method gets a `JSONObject` or `null` from method `buildJsonObject`.

Comment: That is good, now how can I replace the object at dkapps54.github.io/jsonTestApp/message'json?

Comment: Yes. I may even host it somewhere else if editing at github is not possible